# Выровнять текст

Tags: html, css

http://prntscr.com/j8jct1
как можно выравнять текст по правому краю, чтобы буква отзыВ была на равне с буквой работЕ

Comment: убрать пробел наверное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте свойство `text-align: right;` вот пример:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 20px 0 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper span {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>оставить отзыв о нашей работе</span>
</div>
```